# What is wrong with considering $V=4(\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2)$ as $V = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(2x)^2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

To find the energy of the Harmonic Oscillator whose potential is given by $V=4(\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2)$, we consider the following two Cases:

**CASE 1:**

We rewrite $V$ as $V = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(2x)^2$

$\implies V = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2X^2$, where $X = 2x$

$\therefore E = (n+\frac{1}{2})\hbar\omega$

**CASE 2:**

We rewrite $V$ as $V = \frac{1}{2}m(2\omega)^2x^2$

$\therefore E = (n+\frac{1}{2})\hbar(2\omega) = 2(n+\frac{1}{2})\hbar\omega$

The procedure in **CASE 2** is the correct one. But I want to know why the method in **CASE 1** is wrong. What is wrong with considering $X=2x$ and then rewriting $V$ as the potential of the regular Harmonic Oscillator and then getting the energy as the energy of the standard Harmonic Oscillator?

Comment: Have you tried following through the standard derivation of the energy levels (I mean the one with raising/lowering operators $a,a^\dagger$ not the one with the Hermite polynomials) with $X=2x$? You may discover what breaks rather quickly.

Comment: Hi @DomTesilbirthShira and welcome to Physics SE. If your question is closed, you can edit it and it will automatically be considered for reopening by the community. Please don't repost the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You scaled variables improperly. This is the price you pay for not absorbing *m* and *ω* in your variables and keeping track (partial nondimensionalization). In case 2, you simply doubled the angular frequency and got the right answer.

In case 1, you should also scale the  mass, but you did not notice it. Notice the canonical momentum to *X=2x* is now $P=-i\hbar {\partial \over \partial X}=p/2$, so the kinetic term of your hamiltonian is now 4 times the previous one:
$$
H= 4 \left (-{i\hbar^2 \over 2m} \partial^2_X\right )+{m\omega^2\over 2} X^2 
=2\left ( -{i\hbar^2 \over 2M} \partial^2_X  +{M\omega^2\over 2} X^2      \right),
$$
where *M=m/2*. But the energy levels are independent of the mass, so you double the scale of your energy spectrum, as in case 2.

Answer (score 1):

You need the full Schrodinger equation:
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}+4(\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2)\psi=E\psi$$
Can you see that if the ''4" is group with the $\omega$, then you can indeed just substitute $2\omega\equiv\omega'$ for instance and write down the correct solution as
$$E=(n+1/2)\hbar\omega'$$
However, if you want to group the ''4" with the $x$, your potential energy will no longer be a function of the same variable as the kinetic energy ($V(2x)$ vs $T(x)$).  You then can't just quote the energy as
$$E=(n+1/2)\hbar\omega$$
as this is no longer the valid solution.